# Except on Lists in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I count months and years from a given date to the present date
and from this list I have to subtract the months that were returned to me in the sql (linq) query.
I try to use "Except" on the results, but gives me an error in the picture below

```
  var list = _ecpContext.Akceptacje_UnionAll_V
                   .Where(f => f.ADLogin == user)
                   .Select(f => new
                   {
                       Miesiac= f.Miesiac,  //month
                       Rok= f.Rok  // year
                   })
                   .ToList();

//-------------------------------------------------------------------

                DateTime employmentDate = _ecpContext.Ustawienia.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UstLogin == user).EmploymentDate;
                int employmentYear = employmentDate.Year;
                int employmentMonth = employmentDate.Month;

                DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                int currentYear = now.Year;
                int currentMonth = now.Month;

                var newList = Array.Empty<object>().Select(x => new { Month = 1, Year = 1 }).ToList();

                for (var i = employmentYear; i <= currentYear; i++)
                {
                    for (var x = employmentMonth; x <= currentMonth; x++)
                    {
                        newList.Add(new { Month = x, Year = i });
                    }
                }

//-------------------------------------------------------------------

// i try
                IEnumerable<DatesOfShortages> listMissingDates = list.Except(newList);
```

```
 public class DatesOfShortages
    {
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public int Month { get; set; }
    }
```

new error

[image]

Comment: This will not work, since you declare a list of your custom class but you want to assign a list of tuples to it. To me you are in a x-y problem where you'd better take another approach. Furthermore, in your nested loop you will not count months in past years which ont value is < target value, which makes no sense.

Comment: How about `Enumerable.Range(employmentYear, currentYear-employmentYear+1).SelectMany(Year => Enumerable.Range(employmentMonth, currentMonth-employmentMonth+1).Select(Month => new{Month,Year})).ToList();`

Comment: Please give a [mcve] instead of these iterations of you editing incomplete code and getting weird bugs. Stack Overflow is not a debugger.

Comment: You need keep the two compared source with the same property name. Otherwise you may customize `IEqualityComparer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Except` method **is a method** which produces the set difference of two sequences so you need to invoke it.

```
IEnumerable<DatesOfShortages> listMissingDates = newList.Except(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have one list A full of anonymous types, and another list B full of Tuples, and run a.Except(b) on them

Make a list of anonymous types instead of tuples:

```
var newList = Array.Empty<object>().Select(x => new { Month = 1, Year = 1 }).ToList();

for (var i = employmentYear;  i <= currentYear; i++)
{
    for (var x = employmentMonth; x <= currentMonth; x++)
    {
        newList.Add(new{ Month = x, Year = i});
    }
}
```

For `newList` I suppose something like `new [] { list.ElementAtOrDefault(-1) }.ToList();` would work too.. Whatever trick you feel like pulling to get a list of ATs!